# how to implement Restful Service API in ofbiz

Tags: ofbiz, opentaps

i want to implement RESTfull api for ofbiz with authorization and authentication,
i have found an reference [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Export+service+using+REST) but it required username and password every time, i need something like token based authentication.
Any help will be appreciate .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is better to ask this on the user ML of the OFBiz project. See here to find out how to connect: https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

it will required all the time because its authentication otherwise use token instead of password  on service.xml file.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Export+service+using+REST

follow this

thank you